# Using grunt for a custom Project

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am using ***Grunt*** as "JS Task Runner".
Node is installed in "C:/Program Files". 
NPM got installed in C:/users/Peterson/appdata/roaming/npm. 
Grunt, Bower, and Grunt-cli inside npm folder.

Creating a project - D:/Project A. 
Following files inside D:/ProjectA - ***"package.json"*** and ***gruntfile.js***

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test-Project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.3"
  }
}
```

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

    //Read the package.json (optional)
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Metadata.
    meta: {
        basePath: '../',
        srcPath: '../src/',
        deployPath: '../deploy/'
    },

    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
            '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> ',

    // Task configuration.
    concat: {
        options: {
            stripBanners: true
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['<%= meta.srcPath %>scripts/fileone.js', '<%= meta.srcPath %>scripts/filetwo.js'],
            dest: '<%= meta.deployPath %>scripts/app.js'
        }
    }
});

// These plugins provide necessary tasks.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

// Default task
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

};
```

In CLI D:/ProjectA> grunt

```
Fatal Error: Unable to find local grunt
```

Can someone help?

Comment: did you run `npm install` in your `D:/Project A` folder ?

Comment: No I did not. I ran it when I installed node js, so it got installed in C:/users/Peterson/appdata/roaming/npm

Comment: Do I need to run npm again in the 'D:/projectA' directory ?? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed node/npm and the clis of Grunt & Bower (installing them globally via `npm install -g` I assume)

What you're missing is to run `npm install` at the root of your project (where your `package.json` file is), to install your **project dependencies** specified in the `package.json`

Comment: You are right. Your answer worked. But, I am unable to understand, when once I installed npm globally, then why I needed to install it again in my project folder dear?

Comment: You are not installing npm locally. You are installing a local copy of grunt and the grunt plugin grunt-contrib-concat according to your package.json file. There will be more dependencies in the future as your project develops.  http://gruntjs.com/plugins